# conditional match in awk pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script that takes 3 parameters. The first two parameters are always used to do the pattern matching. The third one should be optional. If it's *not passed* then I want to do the match as follows:

```
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end -v code=$code '
  start <= \$1 && \$1 < end {
  ...
  }'
```

if it *is passed* then I want to do the match as follows:

```
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end -v code=$code '
  start <= \$1 && \$1 < end && code = $code {
  ...
  }'
```

How should I express this conditional match in awk patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` with a `or` condition:

```
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end -v code=$code '
  start <= $1 && $1 < end && (code == "" || code == "123") {
  ...
  }'
```

`(code == "" || code == "123")`: Will check condition `code == "123"` only when `code` is not-empty.

Also there is no need to use `\$1`.